# Possible to use GUILayout in GUI.Window?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to use `GUILayout` inside `GUI.Window` ?

```
// Message Box =====
private float msgWindowWidth = 400;
private float msgWindowHeight = 300;
protected Rect rectMsgWindow;
protected bool showMsgWindow = false;

void OnGUI() {
  if(showMsgWindow) {
    GUIStyle msgWindowStyle = new GUIStyle();
    msgWindowStyle.normal.textColor = new Color(1, 1, 1);
    rectMsgWindow = GUI.Window(0, rectMsgWindow, MessageWindow, "Hint", msgWindowStyle);
  }
}

protected void MessageWindow(int windowID) {
  GUILayout.BeginVertical();
  GUILayout.Label("Feature not available yet");
  GUILayout.Space(10);
  if(Button("OK")) {
    showMsgWindow = false;
  }
  GUILayout.EndVertical();
}

// a function that generates GUILayout button
protected bool Button(string label)
{
    return GUILayout.Button(
        label, 
        GUILayout.MinHeight(buttonHeight), 
        GUILayout.MaxWidth(mainWindowWidth)
    );
}
```

Currently it only shows "Hint" in white after `showMsgWindow` is set to `true`. What did I miss to show the GUI Window contents?

p.s. the main reason to use `GUILayout` is to organize the layout well.

Answer (score 0):

To make the codes working, the `GUI.Window` has to be replaced with `GUILayout.Window`. That is:

```
rectMsgWindow = GUI.Window(0, rectMsgWindow, MessageWindow, "Hint", msgWindowStyle);
```

to:

```
rectMsgWindow = GUILayout.Window(0, rectMsgWindow, MessageWindow, "Hint");
```

The reason behind this, is because:

`GUILayout` and `GUI` are different user interface systems in Unity 3D. They won't work if they mix up and load together. Surprisingly Unity does not issue a warning / compile error of this.